# button to trigger contentious dictation

Tags: uwp

I have been stuck for quite a while in my uwp project. I copied the sample from Microsoft and it breaks

```
 if (isListening == false) {
                        // The recognizer can only start listening in a continuous fashion if the recognizer is currently idle.
                        // This prevents an exception from occurring.
                        if (speechRecognizer.State == SpeechRecognizerState.Idle) {
                            isListening = true;
                            await speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync();
                            isListening = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        isListening = false;
                        if (speechRecognizer.State != SpeechRecognizerState.Idle) {
                            // Cancelling recognition prevents any currently recognized speech from
                            // generating a ResultGenerated event. StopAsync() will allow the final session to 
                            // complete.
                            await speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StopAsync();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
        }

        private async void SpeechRecognizer_HypothesisGenerated(
            SpeechRecognizer sender,
            SpeechRecognitionHypothesisGeneratedEventArgs args) {

            string hypothesis = args.Hypothesis.Text;
            string textboxContent = dictateBuilder.ToString() + " " + hypothesis + " ...";

            await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {
                richEbitBox.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.None, textboxContent);
            });
        }

        private async void ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated(
            SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession sender,
            SpeechContinuousRecognitionResultGeneratedEventArgs args) {

            if (args.Result.Confidence == SpeechRecognitionConfidence.Medium ||
                  args.Result.Confidence == SpeechRecognitionConfidence.High) {

                dictateBuilder.Append(args.Result.Text + " ");

                await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {
                    richEbitBox.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.None, dictateBuilder.ToString());
                });
            }
        }

        private void ContinuousRecognitionSession_Completed(
            SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession sender,
            SpeechContinuousRecognitionCompletedEventArgs args) {
        }
```

I am trying to turn on the dictation, when I hit the button and disable it when I hit it again, and everything it breaks, I get an Error telling me that this error is not associated with given text

Comment: Have you modify the official code sample?

Comment: For my testing, the contentious dictation scenario works well.

Comment: Yes I grab it and modify it and does not work. I also have this other version, but I do not know how to stop the speechSyntetizer, when I click the button again [link](https://pastebin.com/2CnG9SX6)

Comment: Please provide the code sample that your have modified with github, I will debug base on your demo.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/WA4caTXy I get the error no text associated with this error

Comment: I checked your code  but it is not complete, I could not use to make sample and reproduce your issue? could you create a blank app and write above then provide us.

Comment: This is all my code

https://pastebin.com/SuctZbVq

Answer (score 0):

> button to trigger contentious dictation

It looks thread issue, I move all `SpeechRecognizer` initialization steps to `OnNavigatedTo` method, and it works with not error.

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    bool permissionGained = await AudioCapturePermissions.RequestMicrophonePermission();
    if (permissionGained)
    {

        dispatcher = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
        var dictationConstraint = new SpeechRecognitionTopicConstraint(SpeechRecognitionScenario.Dictation, "dictation");
        speechRecognizer.StateChanged += SpeechRecognizer_StateChanged;
        speechRecognizer.Constraints.Add(dictationConstraint);
        SpeechRecognitionCompilationResult result = await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();
        if (result.Status != SpeechRecognitionResultStatus.Success)
        {
            return;
        }

        speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.Completed += ContinuousRecognitionSession_Completed;
        speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.ResultGenerated += ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated;
        speechRecognizer.HypothesisGenerated += SpeechRecognizer_HypothesisGenerated;

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

And I have uploaded the case demo [here](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/App51/tree/master/App51) please check.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I have a last question I do not have a OnNavigatedTo, So where do I initialize?

Comment: I Updated the code, but I still have problems, When I try to stop the recognition.
https://pastebin.com/r4hRdcV4

Comment: `OnNavigatedTo` is page override  method, you could copy above and use directly. please check the code [here](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/App51/blob/master/App51/MainPage.xaml.cs#L103), and remove this line  `isListening = false;`.

Comment: if I am not navigating, can I still use it? I thought that OnNavigatedTo and NavigatedFrom is to retrieve values on another xaml page

Comment: `OnNavigatedTo` method will invoke when the page appear. you could init speechRecognizer there.

Comment: If you don't want to init `speechRecognizer ` in `OnNavigatedTo` method, you could try to move it to page `Loaded` method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204923/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-edu).